# alternative values of these resistor in circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, analog, adc, digital-audio

i am working on a spectrum analyzer, concept is to feed audio signal to esp32 and perform FFT at 40000hz sampling rate. I tried MIC input but did not get satisfied by results.
[image]
[link to diagram](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atuline/WLED/assets/media/WLED_Line_In_Wiring.png)
I found this diagram on WLED GitHub page but problem is i don't have 680ohm resistors right now which alternative value should I use? and what is purpose of these resistors here. I am using laptop as audio source. The input voltage range for esp-32 ADC is from 0 to 1.1 V.

Comment: You need to credit whoever drew that schematic. It is site policy. Hit the [edit] link ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're probably only there to provide a reasonable load to whatever is driving the input. Typically this will be the headphone output of an audio device. You can probably leave them out but any value 1k to 10k would probably be fine.

The two capacitors prevent DC getting pulled down to ground.